# XPATH or SAX for Keyword Queries (using PHP)

Tags: php, api, xpath, simplexml, sax

Using PHP, what is the best API calling method for keyword searches that query a large XML file and retrieve relevant search results (which would be shopping products)? The number of search results returned would usually vary between 20 and 1000, and there would be 10 to 20 search results per page.  Would XPATH or SAX be the best method to use? Or any other methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to optimize a single search of the file, or 100 searches per second? If you're doing more than one search then you don't want to parse the whole XML file every time you do a search; you need to hold the parsed document either in memory or in an XML database, so that it can be searched repeatedly (typically using XPath, XQuery, or XSLT).

On the other hand, if it's a one-off, then SAX would be faster - but unless the query is trivial, a lot more programming effort to implement.

Comment: Keywords submitted from a website (for shopping products) would be used to search an entire XML document for matching criteria, then return all relevant search results (much like Google Shopping). There may be 100’s of results returned per search query, with 10 to 20 results per page, allowing the user to navigate through all the pages returned.  I am not sure if utilizing a single search of the file or multiple searches per second would be the most effective method. I am familiar with XPATH, but would need to learn SAX if it is be the best method to use in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I think I'll drop out of this. I don't think I would want to advise on a significant design decision without a lot more background information about the project objectives and constraints.